# Kobayashi's Foundations of Differential Geometry and Pseudogroup of Transformations

Tags: differential-geometry

I've just started studying Kobayashi's Foundations of Differential geometry and I was wondering why the author introduces the concept of "pseudogroup of transformations" in the very beginning of the book. Up to now I haven't found this concept in anywhere else in mathematics, is it an useful tool? Is that concept really needed for studying differential geometry?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> why the author introduces the concept of "pseudogroup of transformations" in the very beginning of the book

A book on differential geometry has to define a smooth manifold somewhere at the beginning. To define a smooth manifold, one has to explain what an atlas is. Kobayashi found a way to shorten the definition of an atlas (and make it easily adaptable to different notions of smoothness) by using the language of a pseudogroup of transformations. The crucial compatibility property of an atlas then simply says that transition maps $\varphi_j\circ \varphi_i$ belong to an appropriate pseudogroup.

> Is that concept really needed for studying differential geometry?

Not explicitly. If you pick a random textbook on differential geometry, chances are that it will not have the term "pseudogroup of transformations" in it. But it will surely have the definition of a "smooth manifold", a part of which (the one concerning the transition maps) conveys the same information as the statement about compatibility with a semigroup in Kobayashi's text.

The term *pseudogroup of transformations* [does come up elsewhere](http://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&q=%22pseudogroup+of+transformations%22&btnG=&as_sdt=1%2C33&as_sdtp=). But for the purposes of reading Kobayashi's book, you can probably forget it, and keep in mind only the  important examples which appear at the bottom of page 1.